# How to work with Loopback address 127.0.0.1?

Tags: network-discovery

127.0.0.1 is used as loopback the address to one's own computer. But how can it be done ? Is it possible for creating a local webpage using this address.? And what kind of a server do we need for using 127.0.0.1. Many softwares make use of 127.0.0.1 for displaying the troubleshooting page with the help of the ports. Is it possible for anyone to create a page and display the page onto his own computer. 
       I have created a webpage which i want to display onto a local computer instead of using the internet. So, i want to make use of IPv4 loopback address..

Comment: Hi Shivam, welcome to NESE. As @RonTrunk pointed out, you will need to bind a service to the IP address (like a HTTP service for Web, etc). But I'm afraid the actual configuration on the server to do that is off topic on this Q&A. You'll have to ask at Server fault, which is more geared towards server configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the loopback as a separate network interface on your computer.  You can ping, or open TCP or UDP connections to it.  If you create a web server on that device, you tell it to listen (bind) on one or more interfaces.  If it is listening on the loopback address, you would browse to 127.0.0.1 to access the server.

Answer (score 0):

Anything sent to an address in the `127.0.0.0/8` range is looped right back into the host. This is used for testing higher-layer protocols, so yes you can use it to test things like web pages. Protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here, so we can't help you configure your web server/browser to do this.

[RFC 5735, Special Use IPv4 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher-level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block loops back inside the host.  This
> is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback.  As
> described in [RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3, addresses within the entire
> 127.0.0.0/8 block do not legitimately appear on any network anywhere.